# Time Profiler for asynchronous requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-instruments

Hi am try to figure out how to use Time Profiler for asynschronous requests. Currently I use NSDate and NSTimeInterval to track the time it takes for a request to return. Here is the code for what I am doing now:

```
NSDate * start = [NSDate date];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/photos?fields=images", albumName] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, FBGraphObject *result, NSError *error) {
    NSTimeInterval timeBetweenDates = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];            
    NSLog(@"Facebook Album Request Time: %f", timeBetweenDates);
        ...
```

Seems like there should be a way to do this Time Profiler. Does time profiler provide this a way to do this? Also, how do I get the profile of events taking place running inside the async request?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In what way is Time Profiler failing to do what you want or expect?

Comment: @KenThomases thank you for your response. I edited my question. I want to get the profile of the async request without using NSDate and NSTimeInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Time Profiler doesn't measure the amount of time that has passed between two points in your code. It samples what your threads are doing at various points. Over a given sampling period, it tells you how your threads allocated their time which is a different question than how much time elapsed between two points in your code. Also, it's statistical in nature.

You can use the DTPerformanceSession framework to [start and stop profiling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewInstruments/NewFeatures40/NewFeatures40.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010950-CH2-SW10) or [emit flags](http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2012/9/18/advanced-profiling-with-the-dtperformancesession-framework.html), but I'm not sure that will achieve what you're looking for either.

As to "how do I get the profile of events taking place running inside the async request", the time profiler should already be effectively showing that. However, you should recognize that the answer may be "nothing". Async APIs are usually asynchronous precisely because they have to wait for some external events and, while they're waiting, your code or even the frameworks are doing nothing. For example, if a request is sent to a remote server and the frameworks are waiting for a reply, they will be idle until the server sends the reply back.

Comment: I don't see percentages for each line of code inside a async request. For example in the completion block of the FB request in my question, I have three lines of code. Unlike, code outside the block, none of them have percentages next to them.

Comment: As I say, time profiling is statistical in nature. Instruments samples your thread every millisecond or whatever and records what it was doing. If your completion handler is not running when the sample is taken, it won't show up. That might happen if it is very fast.